# How to determine whether an instument accepts decimals for qty?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

some instruments accept decimals for strategy.entry qty (eg I can buy 0.01 contract of BTC), however some don't (eg oil futures CL1! accept only whole numbers for contracts). Is there a way to determine in code whether I need to floor my quantity? I was expecting info like this to be in syminfo but I can't seem to find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just in case if anyone is looking for the solution, I've just got an official answer from TradingView:

> Hi, thank you for contacting us. Unfortunately, this feature is not
> yet available in TradingView, each instrument has its own requirements
> for the minimum number of contracts and decimal point of contracts
> that can be bought, which depends on the rules of the broker/stock
> exchange. This information is not yet available in Pine Script, but we
> have taken your request into consideration.

Apparently, it's impossible, and we have to manually set it through custom inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Helo

Try with [syminfo.mintick](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_syminfo%7Bdot%7Dmintick)

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

f_printTable(_text) =>
    var table _printTable = table.new(position.middle_right, 1, 1)
    table.cell(_printTable, 0, 0, _text, bgcolor = color.yellow)

f_printTable('syminfo.mintick: ' + str.tostring(syminfo.mintick))
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at mintick, but it looks like it's a bit different. For example, CL1! has syminfo.pointvalue = 1000, syminfo.mintick = 0.01, but the accepted qty in strategy.enter is only integers (or it floors it if you supply decimals). That shows that the strategy tester knows that it can accept only whole numbers, but I can't figure out from where.